# How can I combine all event handlers at once?

Tags: javascript

Suppose handler of event listener can be added multiple times like below:

```
firstPar.addEventListener("click", myFirstEventHandler, false);
firstPar.addEventListener("click", mySecondEventHandler, false);
etc...
```

So, how can I combine the code so that I could use by shortening:

```
function allHandler(){
  myFirstEventHandler();
  mySecondEventHandler();
}
```

or,

```
function allHandler(){
   return function(){
      myFirstEventHandler();
     mySecondEventHandler();
  }
}
```

So that I could use:

```
firstPar.addEventListener("click",allHandler,false);
```

Or, the other way?

Comment: Is the first allHandler not working? Looks fine to me, except if you need the parameters like the event.

Comment: Did you try these options?  Your first `allHandler()` function works with  `firstPar.addEventListener("click",allHandler,false);`.  It sounds like you're asking here before trying anything.  I'd suggest you try first and then ask a more specific question here when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way is fine but I would include the event:

```
function myFirstEventHnadler (event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // To answer your question in the comments.
}

function mySecondEventHandler (event) {
}

function allHandler(event){
    myFirstEventHandler(event);
    mySecondEventHandler(event);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aUE2L/

Comment: So you can handle it like `event.stopPropagation()`, for example.

Comment: where can I use event.stopPropagation() in my code? As you are passing event parameter in myFirstEventHandler() too... and for this where to put stopPropagation() methods ????

Comment: In any one of those functions. It keeps it from propagating up the DOM. Like if you have a click binding on an image and a click binding on that image's parent div, you could trap the event after the image so the div's binding wouldn't happen. You don't always want that though. Sometimes you have analytics code listening to the document and it relies on click events bubbling up. Use it when you need it.

Comment: I mean I have to use it where? in .addEventListener() there I can use function name only but you are trying to say as example to add stopPropagation() but where in my code???

Comment: In any one of those functions, like I said.

Answer (score 0):

This may introduce scoping complexities, but why not use an anonymous function.

```
firstPar.addEventListener("click", function(){
  myFirstEventHandler(); 
  mySecondEventHandler();
}, false);
```